# How to restrict an IAM user form using KMS key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-kms

I'm trying to create a RDS DB and encrypt it using a CMK, is it possible to restrict myself from using this KMS key? to follow [GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/) rules

Example:
I don't want to be able to decrypt or encrypt, create a snapshot or restore a snapshot from the DB I created.

The key policy I used:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "kms" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    principals {
    type = "AWS"
    identifiers = "${local.arn}"
    }

    actions = [
                "kms:Create*",
                "kms:Describe*",
                "kms:Enable*",
                "kms:List*",
                "kms:Put*",
                "kms:Update*",
                "kms:Revoke*",
                "kms:Disable*",
                "kms:Get*",
                "kms:Delete*",
                "kms:TagResource",
                "kms:UntagResource",
                "kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion",
                "kms:CancelKeyDeletion"
            ]

     resources = ["*"]
    } 
}
```

what is wrong with the policy above?

Comment: Change `effect = "Allow"` to `effect = "Deny"`?.

Comment: That will absolutely restrict me to do anything, even deleting the key, I just want to restrict the ability to encrypt and decrypt. you think the the explicit deny is the best practice? @ArpitJain

Comment: Probably break the policy into two statements, one with the effect = "Allow" and the other with the effect = "Deny" actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ensure that a particular IAM entity (user, role, or group) does not have permission to use a specific KMS key, you can exclude that key from the resources field in your IAM policy and as well set "Effect" of your statement to "Deny" as adviced in the comment.

Try this

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "kms" {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "kms:*",
      "Resource": "${aws_kms_key.your_key.arn}"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "kms:Create*",
        "kms:Describe*",
        "kms:Enable*",
        "kms:List*",
        "kms:Put*",
        "kms:Update*",
        "kms:Revoke*",
        "kms:Disable*",
        "kms:Get*",
        "kms:Delete*",
        "kms:TagResource",
        "kms:UntagResource",
        "kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion",
        "kms:CancelKeyDeletion"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Replace "your_key" with the actual name or ARN of the KMS key you want to exclude.